# What does "basic" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "basic" in the dialogue below mean?

> A: "Some version of the Golden Rule can be found in every culture in the world. It's universal." 
>   B: "I guess it really is that **basic**."

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. One of the expectations on this network of sites is that questions have attempted research on their own. What dictionaries did you consult on the meaning of *basic*? Why does its use here confuse you compared to uses you have seen elsewhere? I encourage you to read through the [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic** is something which is fundamental, or forms the simple basis or foundation of something - in this case the moral code of every civilization in the world.

Answer (score 3):

In common parlance, ***basic*** is often used (somewhat figuratively) to mean ***simple***, but in OP's context it's:

> [**basic**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/basic?s=t) *of, pertaining to, or forming a base; fundamental:
>
>    e.g. - a basic principle; the basic ingredient.*

---

Note [this usage](http://www-physics.lbl.gov/~stapp/searle_4.txt), which clearly shows that not all ***basic*** concepts are ***simple***...

> *I believe that most neurobiologists and most of contemporary science agree **the quantum theory is basic** and should be the foundation of neuroscience*

To paraphrase [Niels Bohr](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Niels_Bohr) - *anyone who thinks quantum theory is simple has not understood it*.